# RHEL 8 Ansible playbooks not working with FIPS enabled

Tags: ssh, ansible, rhel8, fips-140-2

I have two sets of Linux VMs in a GCP (Google cloud) environment: Debian9 and RHEL8. The RHEL8 environment is FIPS-140 enabled, due to security/compliance requirements. None of our Ansible playbooks work with the FIPS-enabled RHEL VMs, but still work fine on the Debian VMs. The Linux control host is Debian9 as well.

For the failed RHEL8 playbooks , seeing this log in the Ansible playbook -vvvv output:

```
ValueError: [digital envelope routines: EVP_DigestInit_ex] disabled for FIPS
```

What are some things I can look at to get these Playbooks working withe RHEL8/FIPS VMs?

Comment: You really need to share more context for the error. This line on its own does not tell us what Ansible is doing when the error occurs.

Comment: You should have a look into the Debian Stretch (9) control node, the Python implementation there, search for the term `ssh EVP_DigestInit_ex disabled for FIPS`, [SSH command execution failing ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559170/), [Red Hat Solution #176633](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/176633) and  https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3496.

Comment: Do you have any more information for this question?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
update-crypto-policies --show
```

If it is set to FIPS, then run:

```
sudo update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT
```

and try to run the playbook

Comment: Beware that this workaround makes the system-wide crypto policies (and thus the whole system) no longer FIPS compliant!

Comment: You should always enclose code snippets and commands in backticks to make your posts more readable.